# Confusion Regarding pip and conda environment

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, pip, anaconda, conda

I am trying to install the [twint](https://github.com/twintproject/twint) library into a conda virtual environment.  I have to use pip because the library is not at the conda or conda forge channels.  twint requires Python 3.6, so I created a new virtual environment with that version.  I created that environment following Anaconda's instructions:

```
conda create --name py36 python=3.6
```

Again following Anaconda's instructions, I install pip to that environment.  A weird thing, I believe, happens here, which is that I am told pip is already installed.

```
MacBook-Pro-89:~ Zack$ conda install -n py36 pip
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: ..........

# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /Users/Zack/anaconda/envs/py36:
#
pip                       20.0.2                     py_2    conda-forge
```

Whether I check my pip version (`which -a pip`) from the py36 environment or not, I am shown the following:

```
(py36) MacBook-Pro-89:~ Zack$ which -a pip
/Users/Zack/anaconda/bin/pip
/Users/Zack/anaconda/bin/pip
/Users/Zack/anaconda/bin/pip
/Users/Zack/anaconda/bin/pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip
```

If I try to install twint, it errors out at multidict.  The error message is very long, so below I show the top and bottom, which shows something about Python 3.5.

```
     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /Users/Zack/anaconda/bin/python /Users/Zack/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/56/sdxbs4_x1xlgyb_9vg9mkn300000gn/T/pip-build-env-exnpi3i_/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'pip>=18' 'setuptools>=40' wheel
           cwd: None
[DELETED BY ME FOR THIS ANSWER]
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/Zack/anaconda/bin/python /Users/Zack/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/56/sdxbs4_x1xlgyb_9vg9mkn300000gn/T/pip-build-env-exnpi3i_/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'pip>=18' 'setuptools>=40' wheel Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have tried with pip3 as well, same error.

I have also tried cloning the twint project from github and installing using the requirements file, but I get a similar error to what I'm seeing already:

```
ERROR: Package 'twint' requires a different Python: 3.5.2 not in '>=3.6.0'
```

I do not think it is a PYTHONPATH issue, as I don't believe I ever set it.

```
MacBook-Pro-89:~ Zack$ echo $PYTHONPATH

MacBook-Pro-89:~ Zack$ source activate py36
(py36) MacBook-Pro-89:~ Zack$ echo $PYTHONPATH

(py36) MacBook-Pro-89:~ Zack$
```

I am pretty sure that I do not have pip in the py36 environment I created, which somehow means it tries using Python 3.5.  What I don't understand is that I do have pip in a py35 environment I created.  I also do not have this problem on a remote desktop I use, where again pip does exist in the Python 3.6 environment.  So there is something funky going on with my py36 environment on my laptop.

Based on the helpful comments below, I have tried the following but also to no avail.  See the comments for my responses.

`install -y python=3.6 pip conda
which pip
/Users/Zack/anaconda/bin/pip`

`python -m pip twint
/Users/Zack/anaconda/envs/py36/bin/python: No module named pip`

I am using a 2016 Macbook Pro with OS X El Capitan.  xcode is updated.

**What am I doing wrong?!?!  Why won't this work?!?!**

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: Try this. Activate your environment and run the following commands: `conda install -y python=3.6 pip conda`. Then run `which python`,  `which conda`, and `which pip`.

Comment: what does `conda list` give you in the `py36` env?

Comment: @Chicodelarosa, my output tells me `'conda' can only be installed into the root environment.`  `/Users/Zack/anaconda/envs/py36/bin/python`, `/Users/Zack/anaconda/envs/py36/bin/conda`, but pip is still `/Users/Zack/anaconda/bin/pip`.

Comment: @FlyingTeller, `conda list` gives a two-column list of ... things installed.  It shows pip is version 20.0.2.  `which pip` then still shows `/Users/Zack/anaconda/bin/pip`.

Comment: @sinoroc, thanks.  However, `python -m pip twint` from within my py36 environment returns `/Users/Zack/anaconda/envs/py36/bin/python: No module named pip`.

Comment: Not too sure about how _conda_ and _anaconda_ work. But I would assume that if `/Zack/anaconda/envs/py36/bin/python -m pip` doesn't work, then _pip_ is not installed (or at least not correctly). You might want to give a try somewhat forcing _conda_ to uninstall _pip_ a couple of times until it disappears from `conda list`, then try to install it again. If it still doesn't clear up things, I would recommend deleting the virtual environment and recreate it from scratch.

Comment: Have you seen https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are having troubles installing pip. An alternative way of installing pip is through [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py  
python get-pip.py
```

Now you can use pip install

```
python -m pip install pip --upgrade
python -m pip install twint
```

Comment: Works, thanks!  @TinNguyen, do you have any idea why installing pip using get-pip.py puts it into my environment while the ways I tried in my question did not?